# Java - Why does DualPivotQuicksort have duplicated code?

Tags: java, arrays, refactoring

Looking at the jdk implementatino of Dual pivot quick sort there is plenty of duplicate code for every type of array. For example:

ints:

```
 static void sort(int[] a, int left, int right,
                 int[] work, int workBase, int workLen) {
    // Use Quicksort on small arrays
    if (right - left < QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD) {
        sort(a, left, right, true);
        return;
    }
```

longs:

```
 static void sort(long[] a, int left, int right,
                 long[] work, int workBase, int workLen) {
    // Use Quicksort on small arrays
    if (right - left < QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD) {
        sort(a, left, right, true);
        return;
    }
```

Why not just use T[] a and benefiting from autoboxing?

Comment: What autoboxing? Try to pass an `int[]` to an `Integer[]` - they are not assignment compatible.

Comment: Autoboxing is exactly why this isn't done. A generic type has to be a reference type meaning you'd have to use `Long` rather than the cheaper `long` since arrays are not covariant. Or is it variant? I always mix those. Either way, `Long[]` is not convertible to `long[]`.

Comment: I didn't notice auto boxing wasn't possible for that case. How about the advent of value types would that allow the use of one generic function for all value types ? http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html

Comment: @Diaa that's definitely something they have in mind for value types, but they're not sure how fully it's going to pan out.  They aren't nearly far enough in working out how value types would look in the first place to be able to say whether or not it would let them deal with this specific issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done for performance reasons. Generic `T[]` cannot be used in place of an array of primitive `int`s or `long`s, so without an overload with `int[]` or `long[]` the users would be forced to use the generic that uses boxed `Long`s and `Integer`s.

You would not be able to benefit from autoboxing here, either, because autoboxing is defined for individual primitives, not for arrays of primitives.

```
private static <T> void doSomething(T[] array){
    ...
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    doSomething(new String[10]); // Compiles fine
    doSomething(new int[10]);    // Compile-time error
}
```

> Main.java:...: error: method doSomething in class ... cannot be applied to given types;
>
> ```
>   doSomething(new int[10]);
>   ^
>  required: T[]
>  found: int[]
> ```
>
> reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>      equality constraints: int
>      upper bounds: Object
>    where T is a type-variable:
>      T extends Object declared in method doSomething(T[])

Even if you could, the processing would be a lot slower, and it would require a lot of additional memory, because wrapping large arrays of primitives could be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Because that would open it to all possible objects, in which case you would need to implement a compareTo method to be able to sort objects in some way.

The compiler keeps it simple. Numbers are nice.

Performance as well, working with objects requires much more memory that working with primitive types.